# How to use the completion handler version of a async function in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, concurrency

I have a async function `func doWork(id: String) async throws -> String`. I want to call this function from a concurrent dispatch queue like this to test some things.

```
for i in 1...100 {
    queue.async {
        obj.doWork(id: "foo") { result, error in 
          ...
        }
    }
}
```

I want to do this because `queue.async { try await obj.doWork() }` is not supported. I get an error:

> Cannot pass function of type '@Sendable () async throws -> Void' to parameter expecting synchronous function type

But the compiler does not provide me with a completion handler version of `doWork(id:)`. When I call it from Obj C, I am able to use the completion handler version: `[obj doWorkWithId: @"foo" completionHandler:^(NSString * val, NSError * _Nullable error) { ... }]`

How do I do something similar in Swift?

Comment: Do you really need a completion handler, or do you just need to wrap your call in `Task { ... }` and then `await` within it?

Comment: You should not combine async await with GCD queues.  Since Objective C doesn't know about Swift async/await, a completion handler wrapper is exposed to the Objective C runtime.  Since Swift supports async/await there is no facility to convert an async.  As @jpndx, a Task is probably what you are looking for

Comment: I am trying to repro an issue within a test and wanted to emulate what happens when obj c code calls my async function from concurrent threads. Can I use `queue.async {  Task { await ... } }` to simulate this?

Comment: The problem is that you’re really not making use of the “concurrent” queue because everything you add to the queue just launches an asynchronous task, returns immediately, and exits the queue although the asynchronous task is still running. That makes no sense. I’d advise revisiting your ObjC code before you worry about reproducing it in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a DispatchQueue. This DispatchQueue will wait for the previous task to complete before proceeding to the next.

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue")

func doWork(id: String) async -> String {
    print("Do id \(id)")
    return id
}

func doWorksConcurrently() {
    for i in 0...100 {
        queue.async {
            Task.init {
                await doWork(id: String(i))
            }
        }
    }
}

doWorksConcurrently()
```

Comment: “This DispatchQueue will wait for the previous task to complete before proceeding to the next” — no, it won’t. The Tasks are not awaited in this example.

Comment: You can try my code. Sleep thread random time at  async doWork and it will print n order from 0 to 100. In a DispatchQueue, task will execute by queue. Multi DispatchQueue, it won't.

Comment: This only works because doWork doesn’t actually do anything async.

Answer (score 0):

You are initiating an asynchronous task and immediately finishing the dispatch without waiting for `doWork` to finish. Thus the dispatch queue is redundant. One could do:

```swift
for i in 1...100 {
    Task {
        let results = try await obj.doWork(id: "foo")
        ...
    }
}
```

Or, if you wanted to catch/display the errors:

```swift
for i in 1...100 {
    Task {
        do {
            let results = try await obj.doWork(id: "foo")
            ...
        } catch {
            print(error)
            throw error
        }
    }
}
```

Now, generally in Swift, we would want to remain within structured concurrency and use a task group. But if you are trying to mirror what you'll experience from Objective-C, the above should be sufficient.

Needless to say, if your Objective-C code is creating a queue solely for the purpose for calling the completion-handler rendition of `doWork`, then the queue is unnecessary there, too. But we cannot comment on that code without seeing it.